# SQLite and Portuguese-br characters

Tags: sqlite, character

I'm developing an app that requires the storage of Portuguese characters. I was wondering if I need to do any configuration to prepare my SQLite db to store those considered special characters. When I query a db table that contains those characters I get a '?' (without quotes) in their place.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an encoding problem. Is your DB/client using UTF-8?
you should check your DB encoding with `PRAGMA encoding;`, be sure your client does it's job using the same encoding and verify that the encoding used handles well those Portuguese chars.

Comment: I'm using sqlite3 on my mac as the client, so it should be handling those just fine... How would I make sure that it is handling Portuguese characters correctly, though? 
I just checked the DB encoding and it returned UTF-8.

Comment: UTF-8 is OK for Portuguese. Either you DB contains '?' (i.e. bad DB alimentation in first place), either your console or client can't handles UTF-8. I would try another client like a scripting language (python) to see what's really in the DB or try to create a new DB and put some of those chars in a table then try your process again with this new DB, to see if you get '?'.